# Integrating Multi-Level Push Menu into a Meteor app

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteorite

I want to integrate the great [Multi-Level Push Menu](http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/) JQuery plugin into my Meteor.js app. I followed the instructions at the homepage and it seems to load. It just won't style right. I'm not sure why that's the case. 
I think I have to package it somehow but it is not loaded into Meteorite. How can I do this?

EDIT:

I'm using the new 0.8 version. I put the jquery.multilevelpushmenu.min.js and the multilevelpushmenu.css in a public folder to load them in.

```
<head>
  <title>menu-test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="multilevelpushmenu.css" />
  <script src="jquery.multilevelpushmenu.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  {{> menu}}

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu();
    });
</script>
</body>

<template name="menu">
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <h2><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>All Categories</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Devices</a>
            <h2><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Devices</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Mobile Phones</a>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Mobile Phones</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Super Smart Phone</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Thin Magic Mobile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Performance Crusher</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Futuristic Experience</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Televisions</a>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Televisions</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Flat Super Screen</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Gigantic LED</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Power Eater</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">3D Experience</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Classic Comfort</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>Cameras</a>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>Cameras</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Smart Shot</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Power Shooter</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Easy Photo Maker</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Super Pixel</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Magazines</a>
            <h2><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Magazines</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">National Geographics</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The Spectator</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Rambler</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Physics World</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The New Scientist</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Store</a>
            <h2><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Store</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i>Clothes</a>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-tags"></i>Clothes</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Women's Clothing</a>
                            <h2><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Women's Clothing</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Tops</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Dresses</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Shoes</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Sale</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>Men's Clothing</a>
                            <h2><i class="fa fa-male"></i>Men's Clothing</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Shoes</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Sale</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Jewelry</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Music</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Grocery</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Collections</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Credits</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: It would be easier to track if you provide a piece of code you did with a clear explanation of what you expected and what you get. Right now the cause could be a missing file, package, errors related to how Spark treats jQuery manipulations, or ants stomping on your CPU. Also, which Meteor version do you have? It's quite important, as the current 0.8.0 changes a lot of UI related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. You have to put the css and js files into public/client/. create a package.js file there which looks lile this:

```
Package.describe({
      summary: "Push Menu with multiple levels"
});

Package.on_use(function (api, where) {
      api.add_files('jquery.multilevelpushmenu.css', 'client');
      api.add_files('jquery.multilevelpushmenu.min.js', 'client');
});
```

Then you have to add your package to your local smart.json file. Like this:

```
{
      "packages": {
        "bootstrap-3": {},
        "multi-level-push-menu": {
          "path": "public/client/"
        }
      }
}
```

Finally you have to run "mrt add multi-level-push-menu"