# multilevel push menu in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, package

i am newbie in meteor and also new member in stackoverflow.. i want to ask about the multi level push menu in meteor.. i got trouble to add the external js file to my meteor app..

i know this question has been asked before, and i already follow it 
[Integrating Multi-Level Push Menu into a Meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718020/integrating-multi-level-push-menu-into-a-meteor-app)

but it still not working on me..by the way, im using meteor 1.1.0.2 (correct me if im wrong, there is no smart.json anymore in this version).. i dont know how to replace the code in smart.json file and i also cannot add the `meteor add multi-level-push-menu` in my cmd ..

i cannot ask in the same thread before because of i dont have 50 reputations..

thanks

Comment: FYI: You cannot "ask in the same thread" on this site anyway. StackOverflow is not a forum. A thread consists of exactly one question and X answers. Posting a question into the answers section is not okay.